# Remove all capabilities in separate method fails versus included in method

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

Removing capabilities with the `remove_all_caps` works if it is run within a method. But if the method calls a separate method with the remove_all_caps then it fails.

This works

```
        $user->set_role('subscriber');
        $user->remove_all_caps();
        $user->remove_role('subscriber');

        foreach ( $wp_role as $value ) {
            $user->add_role( $value );
        }
```

However, I tried to separate out the removing of all capabilities and place it in its own method. This way I could call it several places. Calling the method works, a var_dump shows it is being called. However, the capabilities are not being removed.

The first three lines from above are removed and replaced with:

```
$this->remove_roles();
```

Which is called but never removes the capabilities.

```
/**
 * remove capability from the user and any roles
 */
public function remove_roles() {

    $user_id = $this->visitor['user_id'];
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    $user->set_role('subscriber');
    $user->remove_all_caps();
    $user->remove_role('subscriber');
}
```

Is the line with the new WP_User in the remove_roles the issue? Is there a better way to call the `remove_roles()` method?

Thank you for an explanation.

Comment: Can you show us the context where and when both methods are executed?

Comment: +1 @cybmeta...because it seems to work for me when I incude the `remove_roles()` method in a bare bones plugin class and then call it via `add_action ('init', array ($this, 'remove_roles'))`

Comment: Sure. the login portion of a plugin calls a class with the methods. The first checks if the user is in the database. If yes then the update_user is called, which removes the roles then adds current ones. The remove_roles is called without add_action.